# Logback DBAppender has null caller_filename

Tags: java, mysql, jndi, logback, context.xml

Using `logback-1.0.13.jar` and JDK 1.6u34.

I have a Java web app (WAR) with the following `WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml`:

```
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="5 minutes">
    <appender name="logManager-dbAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>NEUTRAL</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>WARN</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>NEUTRAL</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.JNDIConnectionSource">
            <jndiLocation>java:comp/env/jdbc/dbLogging-local</jndiLocation>
        </connectionSource>
    </appender>

    <root level="ALL">
        <appender-ref ref="logManager-dbAppender" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

And the following `${TOMCAT_HOME}/conf/context.xml` (global `context.xml` for all web apps):

```
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <Resource
        name="jdbc/dbLogging-local"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://my-mysql-server.example.com:3306/my_db"
        username="my_user"
        password="my_password"

        maxActive="20"
    />
</Context>
```

And have the [latest MySQL/JDBC driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) on my runtime classpath at `WEB-INF/lib/mysql-jdbc-5.1.25.jar`). Additionally, because this is a global `context.xml`, I also have the same MySQL/JDBC driver located at `${TOMCAT_HOME}`/lib.

And am getting the following stack trace:

```
08:54:52,905 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender[logManager-dbAppender] - problem appending event com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'caller_filename' cannot be null
    at com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'caller_filename' cannot be null
    at  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1040)
    at  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2734)
    at  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
    at  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
    at  at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at  at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender.subAppend(DBAppender.java:105)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender.subAppend(DBAppender.java:42)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.db.DBAppenderBase.append(DBAppenderBase.java:108)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend(UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.java:88)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:48)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(Logger.java:272)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callAppenders(Logger.java:259)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:441)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:395)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.info(Logger.java:599)
    at  at com.myapp.server.DummyServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
    at  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Any ideas as to why I'm getting the MySQL exception? I found [this similar unanswered question](http://logback.10977.n7.nabble.com/caller-filename-cannot-be-null-in-DBAppender-td584.html) on Old Nabble and am wondering if it's a long-standing bug...?

It seems to be connecting to my MySQL server and inserting a NULL `logging_event.caller_filename` when (per the Logback DBAppender's onw DDL) NULLs are not allowed on that column.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problem with PostgreSQL and logback 1.0.7 with slf4j 1.6.6
Somehow it seems the caller information is not "always" passed what leads to this problem, that in turn means the concerned logging call doesn't make to database (and if there isn't debug="true" on logback configuration, you don't even know it).

As a dummy resolution, one can relax the database column constraints in the logging tables (not require "not null" in caller columns). In my case however, it turned out it matters how I construct logger instances in code: while this has caused the above failure

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(My.class);
```

this worked fine (i.e. filled the caller information)

```
Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(My.class.getName());
```

I can't explain it though.