# Logback DBAppender writing NULLS to caller_filename column

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

I'm using Logback with the DBAppender in a Windows service to persist log entries into a MSSQL database. The code is in java and is written with the SpringBoot framework. When I run the project in Eclipse everything works perfectly, including the test that persist log entries using Logback with the DBAppender. However when I do the SpringBoot build to bundle it into the final SpringBoot jar with the typical SpringBoot packaging structure and then run it as a service the overall project runs great except the tests that persist log entries into the DB. After a lot of investigating and with help from my company's DBA we discovered that the DBAppender is attempting to write NULL's in the caller_filename column. This is one of Logback's standard columns used and is included when you use Logback's SQL script to generate the tables needed in the DB for Logback to run correctly.
I did try the suggestion from another SO post [Logback DBAppender has null caller_filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918804/logback-dbappender-has-null-caller-filename) that describes the pretty much the same problem, (not sure that person was running it as a service) and a workaround for the problem. The workaround was to relax the NO NULL constraint. I did in fact write the script to disable NULL checking and my service now persists the DB records except of course the caller_filename column, which has "NULL" in each of the rows. I believe the caller_filename is supposed to contain the loggers name that's used when you call LoggerFactory.getLogger("LoggerName").
About 6 months back I ran into what I think was the same problem with Apache's Batik for rendering SVG. The very short story is, Batik jars contain certain resources, in this case if I remember correctly was either an XML file or XML schema. When I ran my program as a service it would fail. Some serious debugging effort revealed SpringBoot was using its own class loader to try to load the file but could not. It was returning file not found. After much more investigating I found out a way to circumvent SpringBoot's loader and use the REAL JVM's class loader to handle the BATIK jars. I made a special directory and moved all of Batik's jars into that folder and added the additional JVM option "-Dloader.path=batlib/"
That fixed Batik's problem. I tried the same with this new Logback DBAppender problem but it didn't fix it.
I'm still fairly convinced this new bug is also SpringBoot problem, with a slim chance of it being a Windows Service related issue.

Does anyone have any nuggets of wisdom on this. So far I have see NO discussions about the Batik problem discussed on the WEB and only one post, the one mentioned above about the DBAppender being used in a Windows Service with SpringBoot.

Thanks much
Al Harper